# Is there a way in jQuery or Javascript to determine the speed of a touchmove event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, touch-event, touchmove

this is a simple question. 
Is there a way in jQuery or Javascript to determine the speed of a touchmove event?
I use css to grab the element and make it grabable, this works fine but if I move the finger faster, it's less likely I can move to a threshold distance but I did intend to turn page, so is there a way I can determine the speed of movement on the touch move event in javascript or jQuery, and I can adjust the threshold to a smaller value to compensate the speed?

```
    var startX, endX, difference, threshold; 
var startTime, endTime, timeDiff = 151;
$('#animate')
.bind("touchstart", function (e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var d = new Date();      
    startTime = d.getTime();
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX; //starting point
    })
.bind("touchmove", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    endX =e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX; //Get the information for finger 
    difference = startX - endX;  //calculate the distance moved.
    var moved = minusScreen - difference; //determine the affected css value.
    $(this).css("left",moved);  //this makes the element moves with my finger.
    })
.bind("touchend", function (e) { 
    var date = new Date();
    endTime = date.getTime();
    threshold = Math.abs(difference);
    timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
    if ((threshold > (screenWidth * 0.4)) || (timeDiff < 150))  //make the animation move only when the finger moved more than 30% of the page.
        {           
        if (endX > startX) turnLeft();
        else if (endX == startX) {} // havent decide what to do yet 
        else turnRight();
    } else {
        $(this).animate({"left": minusScreen}, 100);
    }
    startX=0; //set the value back to initial.
    endX=0;   //set the value back to initial.});
    });
```

thank's for your great answer. the above is modified code. worked great!!!

Comment: get the time on the touchstart and on touchend calculate `abs(endX-startX)/endTime-startTime` this is now your overall touchmove speed in px/ms

Comment: @jakee seems legit.  Post it as the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

get the time on the touchstart and again on touchend like this

`startTime = new Date().getTime()` and `endTime = new Date().getTime()`

then calculate `var speed = abs(endX-startX)/(endTime-startTime)` this is now your overall touchmove speed in px/ms

Comment: tried, modified the code and its not working. it looked like the both value are given at the same time when touch ends. the results are two same time values.

Comment: well I hate to say, but you initialize ONE date and then ask it for it's time twice... go `startTime = new Date().getTime()` and `endTime = new Date().getTime()`

Comment: yes, worked. thank you! I'm gonna do a bit tidy up work later.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, it seems that there is a "timeStamp" in touch event object, so it might be simpler and faster to simply use :

```
startTime = e.timeStamp();
```

in place of :

```
var d = new Date();      
startTime = d.getTime();
```

Same thing for  var endTime

Comment: `e.timeStamp` is a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` or `DOMTimeStamp`, not a `Function`, and on Firefox this returns nanoseconds instead of millseconds due to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238041 which has been open since 2004. It is also not supported on Android or Chrome until relatively recently. Use `Date.now()`.